# sending sms or push notification with a link to an iPhone application

Tags: ios, sms

Is it possible to send an SMS or a push notification with a link to a specific action in an ios application.
For instance, I'm trying to implement password reset in iPhone application. Due to some restrictions I can't use emails. I know how to send push notifications. The question is, is it possible to embed a link with a token which would open a particular view in particular application and pass that token through?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a link in an SMS which would launch your app (or another app for that matter if it supports URL launching) if the user clicked on that link within the SMS and the link could contain the token which gets passed through to the app.

You can't put a link into a push notification but there's no need to because when the user clicks on the notification your app would automatically get launched (and passed any data such as the token you have embedded within the push notification). 
(You cannot launch another arbitrary app from a push notification).

Comment: thanks for the answer! Can you please point to any documentation how to pass around a token in push notification.

Comment: The apple push notification guide has full details about how to put whatever you want in a push https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Comment: @Gruntcakes Does the second part of your reply apply for both iOS and Android?

Comment: @Grountcakes can you show example of code to add link to SMS?  I have a similar use case here with no luck yet on how to achieve:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239517/android-deliver-plain-text-data-to-another-app-user-with-clickable-image-via-sm

Comment: @AJW it was years since I posted this and I don't have any examples. But if you search the  documentation about launching an app via an app URL you should be able to find info.